# answers Solving puzzles with Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, puzzle

**Hi, I want to calculate the values of these numbers a, b and c.
The only information I have:**

a = √((b-c)²)

b = a * c

c = (a+b)/2

Anyone knows where to begin?

Comment: ...and you have already tried using `Solve[]` on these equations?

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! If you're new to Mathematica, check out the help docs by clicking "help" in the top right hand corner of a Mathematica notebook window. Then try searching for `Solve`. You can also search for anything else. An example of an equation stated in mathematica is `a == Sqrt[(b - c)^2]`. Try learning how `Solve` works and writing down your equations, and if you get stuck, come back! :) Also check out [the most common pitfalls awaiting new users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users), which is quite thorough.